# How to manage unit tests snapshots for components containing theme data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, themes, snapshot

let's assume this easy example with a component and a unit test

**component.jsx**

```
const theme = process.env.THEME

export const Component = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <>
        <h2>{theme} {title}</h2>
    </>
  )
}
```

**component.test.jsx**

```
import { Component } from './Component'

describe('<Component />', () => {
  it('renders properly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Context {...props} />)
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

The project I'm running depends on the const *theme*, so in my pipeline I've more builds, more deploys, one per theme.
Of course the snapshots fail due to the fact that every time I run the *toMatchSnapshot()* functionality, it writes / checks the output in the folder `./__snapshots__`, so the test for the first theme runs succesfully, then it fails for the others.

Are there solutions to this problem?

1. Provide the *theme* as prop to every component (terrible approach)
2. Avoid snapshots for these components (not so good approach because I would like to keep this functionality on for my test suite)
3. Use React.createContext (good approach but it requires a bit of refactoring across the project)

Is there something even better I could try to use?
Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React.createContext with a mocked context data for testing is the best approach indeed.